# PHP regex to detect website URL only and not email

Tags: php, regex

I have tried quite alot of regex but most of them detect email as well.

For example,

`http://www.google.com` is detected correctly.
However, email link also detected `andreweuwhd38@hotmail.com`

Regex tried:

```
#[-a-zA-Z0-9:%_\+.~\#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~\#?&//=]*)?#si
#((http|https|ftp)://(\S*?\.\S*?))(\s|\;|\)|\]|\[|\{|\}|,|\"|'|:|\<|$|\.\s)#
#[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~\#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~\#?&//=]*)?#si
```

I cannot use `FILTER_VALIDATE` function, as I need to capture url and make changes to it.

Comment: You can try [Regexrs](http://www.regexr.com/38vsq) approach or you can find another one that suits your needs

Answer (score 0):

I guess this one would be a ( quite good generic regex ) for regular urls ( not using usernames, ports, unicode caracters .. )

`(ht|f)tp(s?):\/{2}(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+\.)?([a-z0-9-]+\.)?([a-z]{2,4})([a-z0-9\/?&=_()#-]*)`

Comment: what about : 

`(ht|f)tp(s?):\/{2}(www\.)?([a-z0-9]+\.)?([a-z0-9]+)?(\.[a-z]{2,4})([a-z0-9\/?&=_()#-]*)` ?

can't always figure all possible cases ..

Comment: It's the same except a dot in front of `aaa`